iptables hashlimit parameters not applied
Setup
I have the following iptables rule:
-p tcp -m tcp --dport 8885 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 1000/s --hashlimit-burst 2000/s --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name mqttdos -j DROP

To verify, I checked iptables -L -vn:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 2215 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8885 limit: above 1000/sec burst 2000 mode srcip

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

All other tables are empty/ACCEPT.
My test
I'm sending requests from another machine (in this case the host of the above, which is an lxc container; both run Ubuntu 20.04):
while :; do curl -s 10.24.150.126:8885 > /dev/null; echo -n "$?"; sleep 0.01; done

And what I see is bursts of around 20 requests, then 1 second delay, and then another burst of 20 requests.
For comparison, if I sent the request to a destination port that is not limited, e.g.:
while :; do curl -s 10.24.150.126:8888 > /dev/null; echo -n "$?"; sleep 0.01; done

then I see the roughly 100 requests per second that I would expect from this while loop.
Increasing the hashlimit-above value or the hashlimit-burst value has no effect. Interestingly, even if I increase the --hashlimit-htable-expire to something high like 200000, I don't see this take any effect when I check using cat /proc/net/ipt_hashlimit/mqttdos. It still shows the timeout of the bucket as 5 seconds, e.g.:
5 10.24.150.1:0->0.0.0.0:0 2748779220480 13743895300000 2748779060000

What am I doing wrong? why are my hashlimit parameters not applied?
